# Move Multiple marker with their live location at my end

Tags: ios, swift

I am building an application where I have to move multiple marker. These markers will be visible at my end according to the multiple user's live locations. I am able to update only a single marker. but the rest are not updating. I stored these data in firebase and I am getting their data from there.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
        {
            self.hideHUD()

            self.latitudeFloatValue = (dictionary["lat"] as! Double)
            self.longitudeFloatValue = (dictionary["long"] as! Double)

            self.moveMent.delegate = self

            //set old coordinate
            self.oldCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.latitudeFloatValue, self.longitudeFloatValue)
            print(self.oldCoordinate)

            // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the marker
            let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: self.latitudeFloatValue, longitude: self.longitudeFloatValue , zoom: 14)
            self.mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
            self.mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            self.mapView.delegate = self
            self.view = self.mapView

            // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
            self.driverMarker = GMSMarker()
            self.driverMarker.position = self.oldCoordinate!
            self.driverMarker.icon = UIImage(named: "car")
            self.driverMarker.map = self.mapView

            self.copyCordinates = self.cordinates
            print(self.copyCordinates)
            print(self.cordinates)

            self.cordinates = ["lattitude":self.latitudeFloatValue,"longitude":self.longitudeFloatValue]
            print("self.cordinates",self.cordinates)
            print(self.oldCordinates)
            print(self.newCordinates)

            if(self.oldCordinates["lattitude"] == nil)
            {
                self.oldCordinates = self.cordinates
                self.newCordinates = self.cordinates
            }
            self.newCordinates = self.cordinates
            self.oldCordinates = self.copyCordinates

            print("oldCordinates",self.oldCordinates)
            print("newCordinates",self.newCordinates)

            self.movinfMarker()
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)

    //for use in background
    self.locman.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    locman.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways){
        guard let currentLocation = locman.location else {
            return
        }
        stringLatitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
        stringLongitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
        print(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
        print(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    }

    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the marker
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: stringLatitude, longitude: stringLongitude , zoom: 7)
    self.mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    self.mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    self.mapView.delegate = self
    self.view = self.mapView

    Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
        {
            self.latitudeFloatValue = (dictionary["lat"] as! Double)
            self.longitudeFloatValue = (dictionary["long"] as! Double)
            self.titleMarker = (dictionary["username"] as! String)
            self.uuidValue = (dictionary["uuid"] as! String)

            self.states = [
                State(name: self.titleMarker, uuid: self.uuidValue, long: self.longitudeFloatValue, lat: self.latitudeFloatValue),
                ]
        }
        for state in self.states {
            // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
            let state_marker = GMSMarker()
            state_marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: state.lat, longitude: state.long)
            state_marker.icon = UIImage(named: "car")
            state_marker.title = state.name
            state_marker.userData = state.uuid//zIndex = Int32(state.uuid)!
            state_marker.snippet = "Hey, this is \(state.name)"
            state_marker.map = self.mapView
            self.markerDict[state.name] = state_marker
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}



func movinfMarker(){

    driverMarker.map = nil

    let oldCoodinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D? = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.oldCordinates["lattitude"] ?? 0.0 , longitude: self.oldCordinates["longitude"] ?? 0.0)
    let newCoodinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D? = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.newCordinates["lattitude"] ?? 0.0 , longitude: self.newCordinates["longitude"] ?? 0.0)

    print("oldCordinatesNewWala",oldCoodinate as Any)
    print("newCordinatesNewWala",newCoodinate as Any)

    driverMarker.icon = UIImage(named: "car")
    mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: newCoodinate!, zoom: 17)

    driverMarker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0.5), y: CGFloat(0.5))
    driverMarker.position = oldCoodinate ?? CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0,longitude: 0.0)
    //this can be old position to make car movement to new position
    driverMarker.map = mapView
    //marker movement animation
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setValue(Int(2.0), forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({() -> Void in
        self.driverMarker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0.5), y: CGFloat(0.5))
        //New bearing value from backend after car movement is done
    })
    driverMarker.position = newCoodinate ?? CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0,longitude: 0.0)
    //this can be new position after car moved from old position to new position with animation
    driverMarker.map = mapView
    driverMarker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0.5), y: CGFloat(0.5))
    //found bearing value by calculation
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Comment: its correct your  map will update single marker at a time as you have used . childChanged observer which only gets one record at a time.

Comment: But how can I update all my markers one by one. Please suggest. And map is also fluctuating when location changes. How to resolve that issue too ?

Comment: you may get all users with live status and using user id you may update location from previous location to new location. for fluctuating issue you may need some threading to do UI task in foreground and other in background.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan let me check. and thanks for your response. I will come back to you with updated answer.

Comment: sure...no problem

Comment: @AbuUlHassan I am not able to perform the task completely. Please suggest me through code. It would be very useful.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest.

Comment: sorry i was out 
 Database.database().reference().child("users").where("live").isEqual(true)
and then run a loop on snapshot to update locations

Comment: @AbuUlHassan One more thing, what would be the observer event .childchanged or .childAdded ? When .childAdded is used we gets all firebase data or when .childChanged id used we gets only single recored that is changed. So what observer should I use ?

Comment: it will be changed

Comment: but i will suggest you to create a new table for liveUsers and add a user in this table  when user is live and remove when user is going offline and work on that.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan thanks for your response. I am very pleased with your feedback. Thanks again.

Comment: pleasure is all mine